# admob : changing ads

Tags: android, admob

I use following code to show ads in onCreate() of the activity
Since my activity is displayed for longer times, can I refresh the ads ? or will it automatically refresh them ? Do I even need to change them or should not bother it ?

```
        //only ask for test ad, in emulator , should remove this later in real device
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        //adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);               // Emulator
        //adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");                

         // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "908908098098");

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"    

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adLayout);

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change app settings in admob account:

[image]

Also you should remove test mode before publishing:

```
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

In onDestroy(): `adView.destroy();`

In layout:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

In AdMob app settings select this: Disable test mode for all requests

Comment: thanks, is there a guide on what the refresh rate should be ?

Comment: I use 30 secons in my app, but I have noticed that admob refresh it even more frequently. For me - it's good refresh rate.

Comment: my current setting in admob was Use refresh rate set in client code and there no refresh rate in client set, .. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Admob ads are refreshed at a rate set up on your admob account. Go to your account, click on "Manage Settings", then "App Settings", and look for the auto refresh parameters there.

Answer (score 0):

declare adView in activity as data member , then create Timer Task as bellow in your constructor of the activity

```
adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
                }
            });

        }
    };

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 1000 * 60);
```